# hql many to many relation where info is contained in the join table

Tags: java, many-to-many, hql

I have two entities Race and Player, and hibernate created 1 table race_player as Race and Players are linked by a ManyToMany relation.

I need to get the list of the races with :

- the status "available"
- more than 1 player registered for each of these races.

I've been searching the whole day to get in hql format the following query :

select racename
from race
where status = 'available'
and idrace in (
  select raceid
  from race_player
  group by raceid
  having count(raceid) > 1);

The problem is that the table race_player cannot be used in a hql query.

I don't see how I can get this information as the number of player is only referenced in the race_player table.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Sounds more like a many-to-one-to-many relationship, where you need an object to represent the relationship (the 'one' in the middle).

Comment: show your entities mapping

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. You can't use race-player table in hql as there is no class mapped to that table directly. You would have list of players in Race class. 
Try to use:

```
Select raceName from Race r where r.status = 'available' and r.playersList.size >1
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I was very close to find the solution. In fact, it was a syntax problem. Raman, I tried your solution and it was almost correct. I had to write the request without spaces between the string comparison, like this :

```
Select raceName from Race r where r.status='available' and r.playersList.size >1
```

Creazy isn't it ? I've lost many hours and a few hairs but finally so happy to make this sh*t running without exceptions. Once again, thank you !